# How to store only ID in dropdown Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-options

```
<div class="form-group">                           
    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Section Id</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select ng-model="product.sectionId" class="form-control" ng-options="section.name for section in sections track by section.id">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code, I populate the `sections` object via JSON and `section has id,name`. I want to store only `section.id` in my `product.sectionId` but it stores both section id and name as below
`"sectionId":{"id":"Iron Man","name":"Superman"}`. I want only the id to be stored. Is there a way to do that. Im new to bootstrap and angularjs please help me. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your [**`ng-option`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to

**Markup**

```
ng-options="section.id as section.name for section in sections"
```

This will should `section.name` and select `section.id` when you select any of the option.

[**Direct From Docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

> Do not use select as and track by in the same expression. They are not
>   designed to work together.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. But the selected option was not displayed in the dropdown box. Removed 'track by section.id' and the option was displayed. Is it compulsary that track by should be present @pankajparkar

Comment: @FeroozKhan you must  have to remove it..if you see the docs here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions they putted warning that both shouldn't be used together..